# Using fink to install from a website

Tags: web, smalltalk, fink

I want to use fink to install smalltalk. I found [this](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/smalltalk?rel_id=10.5-i386-current-unstable) on the fink website. I was wondering if there was some way to install smalltalk from the url (`sudo fink install smalltalk` does not work). Is there a way to do this? Or do I not understand fink correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smalltalk package is in the unstable branch of fink, so you need to temporarily enable unstable branches to download it.

From [their FAQ](http://www.finkproject.org/faq/usage-fink.php?phpLang=en#unstable):

> ### There's this package in unstable that I want to install, but the fink command just says 'no package found'. How can I install it?
>
> For fink-0.26 and later: If you run fink configure one of the questions will ask whether you want to turn the unstable trees on.
>
> None of these options actually
>   download the unstable tree's package
>   descriptions.You'll need to turn on
>   rsync or cvs updating to do this,
>   which is not set up by default on a
>   new Fink installation. The following
>   command sequence will set you up on a
>   new Fink installation:
>
> ```
> fink selfupdate
> ```
>
> followed by
>
> ```
> fink selfupdate-rsync
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> fink selfupdate-cvs
> ```
>
> and then
>
> ```
>  fink index -f fink scanpackages
> ```
>
> Note: There are Fink Commander analogs
>   for everything except fink index -f.
>   You will have to use the command line
>   for that.
>
> If you're already set up with rsync or
>   cvs updating, then the following
>   command sequence (or the Fink
>   Commander analogs) will suffice:
>
> ```
> fink selfupdate 
> fink index 
> fink scanpackages
> ```